# Why do HK restaurants' wok fried scallops stay big? My pan fried ones at home shrink!

Tags: chinese-cuisine, scallops

In Toronto Canada, I've bought different BIG, raw scallop species like at Whole Foods Market. They are big like HK restaurants'. After I add oil to pan on cook top and stir fry them, they shrink. Why?   See photos –

[image]

[image]

Now see HK restaurants' wok fried scallops  Jade Scallops – 西蘭花炒帶子  in Chinese. Top to bottom – [House of Canton in Kowloon Tong](https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/p-%E7%BF%B0%E9%A8%B0%E9%96%A3-p2207372) (first photo beneath),[Ming Kee Restaurant in Wan Chai](https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/p-%E8%A5%BF%E8%98%AD%E8%8A%B1%E7%82%92%E5%B8%B6%E5%AD%90-%E6%98%8E%E8%A8%98%E9%A3%AF%E5%BA%97-p145108), [金龍冰室](https://s.openrice.com/QrbJ0VTs600) in Tai Po  大埔, [Joy Point Dim Sum](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-joy-point-dim-sum-p7296384) in Tsim Sha Tsui.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these scallops are wok fried? They don't look fried to me, more like steamed.

Comment: It's quite possible they begin with larger scallops + yours are probably cooking longer and differently...see your other question on the same topic.

Comment: Gut feeling: the process described in @moscafj’s answer for your other question is probably also the answer to this one.

Comment: Because you don't wok fry them! You boil or steam them until fully cooked and then stir fry them at high heat for very short time. This is a basic principle, I might say, of Chinese stir fries.

Comment: it's going to be the same answer from your other question https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103429/how-do-hk-restaurants-keep-wok-fried-scallops-white-with-no-visible-sear-marks

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the scallops shrinking, it could simply be the difference in dry vs. wet scallops. Most grocery stores sell wet scallops. At times, dry scallops can be quite hard to find at retail. Wet scallops naturally shrink because of the loss of so much moisture when cooking.

Also, the higher the heat and longer the cook time, the more the moisture is lost.

Comment: They may also be starting with larger scallops too.